# mysql clause where not null in php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

I am making a query which is not working. I want to get data where column of pic in is not empty in all_destination table, also I am using join in my query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `travels_detail` 
INNER JOIN all_destination ON travels_detail.destination = all_destination.destination
WHERE all_destination.pic IS NOT NULL
```

whats wrong in my query?

Comment: What exactly is not working? Please provide more details

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

You should check what is the error returned by MySQL. It will tell you what is the error.

Comment: its not giving me error. its giving me the results which also include null values of column(pic), which i did not require.

Comment: So your query is working... but the result is not what you expect. You should update your question with the new detail provided (null values are included in the result)

Answer (score 0):

You just want to remove the `IS NOT NULL` check and just have

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `travels_detail` 
INNER JOIN all_destination ON travels_detail.destination = all_destination.destination
WHERE all_destination.pic;
```

This will only return records where `all_destination.pic` has been set.

Comment: its giving me 0 result after removing not null

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using @HarrisKhan? Also, can I see some records from the table you would be expecting to see / not see?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT td.some_attribute
FROM  travels_detail as td
INNER JOIN all_destination as ad  ON td.destination = ad.destination
WHERE ad.pic IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.. It mostly works

```
SELECT * FROM `travels_detail` INNER JOIN all_destination ON travels_detail.destination = all_destination.destination WHERE all_destination.pic ! = ""
```